# GNU Make: Check number of parallel jobs

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to add a quick check to a (GNU) makefile which can alert the user to the availability of `-j`/`--jobs` (parallel make). That is, something like

```
$ make
  TIP: this will build faster if you use use "make -j"
  Building ..

$ make -j 
  Building in parallel ..
```

**How can I determine the number of parallel jobs when a Makefile is executed?**

There is a trick here 
http://blog.jgc.org/2015/03/gnu-make-insanity-finding-value-of-j.html

and a proposed change to GNU Make itself here
https://github.com/esantoro/make/commit/b0334e7f3009dc58dbc8e6e6fdec94711537fb3b

but perhaps there is something newer and/or easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest/best solution is to upgrade your version of GNU make to 4.2 or above.  Starting with that version, the `MAKEFLAGS` variable will provide the full `-j` option including the number.  The NEWS file says:

> - The amount of parallelism can be determined by querying MAKEFLAGS, even when
>   the job server is enabled (previously MAKEFLAGS would always contain only
>   "-j", with no number, when job server was enabled).

So:

```sh
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
    ...

$ echo 'all:;@echo $(MAKEFLAGS)' | make -f-

$ echo 'all:;@echo $(MAKEFLAGS)' | make -f- -j
-j
$ echo 'all:;@echo $(MAKEFLAGS)' | make -f- -j10
-j10 --jobserver-auth=3,4
$ echo 'all:;@echo $(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))' | make -f- -j10
10
```

Answer (score 6):

You can determine the number of jobs easier and faster than that blog proposes by using [make Jobserver protocol](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/POSIX-Jobserver.html#POSIX-Jobserver):

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

all:
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory job_count_test

job_count_test: 
    @+[[ "${MAKEFLAGS}" =~ --jobserver[^=]+=([0-9]+),([0-9]+) ]] && ( J=""; while read -t0 -u $${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; do read -N1 -u $${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; J="$${J}$${REPLY}"; done; echo "Building with $$(expr 1 + $${#J}) jobs."; echo -n $$J >&$${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ) || echo "TIP: this will build faster if you use use \"make -j$$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)\""

.PHONY: all job_count_test
```

And then:

```
$ make 
TIP: this will build faster if you use use "make -j8"
$ make -j12
Building with 12 jobs.
```